# How to unload a web browser in WPF, C#

Tags: c#, wpf, webbrowser-control

I am developing a player where each topic could be in a different file type (video, Pdf file, or HTML file). So when the player clicks on any topic the player should unload the previous data type and show the new one.
The problematic scenario is when the player clicks on a topic with HTML file format (the HTML file has an audio file embedded) and then clicks on any topic with any other type. It seems that the HTML file is still running on the back and the sounds get mixed up.
So I try to release the WebBrowser content using the code below:

```
                var web = new WebBrowser;
                web.Source = null;
                web.Dispose();
```

This solves the problem when the application runs on a PC connected to the internet. However, when the same application is run on a PC connected to an intranet the WebBrowser stills runs in the background.
I would be really happy if you could help me and I hope I could explain the problem clear enough.
Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Did you try to navigate to a blank page?: `web.Navigate(default(Uri));`

Comment: I think the real question here is, what component is playing the sound from a visited html-page and how to stop it doing so? This could get somewhat complicated... How's about @mm8's comment or navigating to `about:blank` (@mm8 is `default(Uri)` the same?)?

Answer (score 0):

No . You should not create a new instance of the `WebBrowser` class and null the same Source value, but null the existing instance.

use

```
existingWebBrowser.Source = null;
```

Comment: Well, Actually I get the existing web Browser, I just changed it here. My webbrowser is child of Grid. So I get that child as a WebBrowser and change its source.